# Python Timedelta64 convert days to months

Tags: python, timedelta, python-datetime

I have a Pandas dataframe with 2 columns representing a start-timestamp and an end-timestamp:

```
start       end
2016-06-13  2016-07-20
```

The datatype of these columns is `datetime64[ns]`.

I now want to create a new column showing the difference in months:

```
start       end         duration
2016-06-13  2016-07-20  1.1
```

What I tried is to dow the following:

```
df['duration'] = df['end'] - df['start']
```

The result looks like this:

```
start       end         duration
2016-06-13  2016-07-20  37 days 00:00:00.000000000
```

I then tried to do the following:

```
df['duration'] = df['end'] - df['start']).dt.months
```

But this yields the following error

> AttributeError: 'TimedeltaProperties' object has no attribute 'months'

The datatype of the `duration` column is `timedelta64[ns]`.

How can I achieve the desired result?

Comment: What counts as *a* month... is it a fixed number of days or something else... Is 37 days on from January 31st - 1 month or two months?

Comment: ideally it should be the true value of the amount of days of the month that lies between the start and end dates.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question in the comment though... it'd help if you explain the exact rules of what a month is or isn't and provide some examples of inputs/outputs... A simple approach is just to say a month is 30 days (or N other amount) and that's a simple division... anything more complicated than that needs rules defined for expected results...

Comment: the more i think about it, the less trivial it gets :) i guess i don't know for sure what I want. Probably just a simple solution to get the number of months (e.g. with a fixed amount of days that is 30) between two dates.

Comment: Just take the number of days and divide by 30 then :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import numpy as np #version: 1.16.2
import pandas as pd #version: 0.25.1

df['duration'] = (df['end'] - df['start'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

Comment: This is actually a neat answer!

Answer (score 2):

The previous code no more works in the recent versions of numpy.

###### TypeError: Cannot get a common metadata divisor for NumPy datetime metadata [D] and [M] because they have incompatible nonlinear base time units

```
import numpy as np #version: 1.18.5
import pandas as pd #version: 1.1.5
df['duration'] = (df['end'] - df['start']).astype('timedelta64[M]')/np.timedelta64(1, 'M')
```

Answer (score 0):

Months 'M' unit is deprecated in last versions and will raise an error 'Unit M is not supported'.
So we can simply use days 'D' difference devided by 30.

```
df['duration'] = (df['end'] - df['start'])/np.timedelta64(1, 'D')/30
```

Or for precise calculations for longer periods use 'to_period'

```
df['duration'] = (pd.to_datetime(df['end']).to_period('M') - 
                  pd.to_datetime(df['start']).to_period('M')
                  ).apply(lambda x: x.n)
```